# EclipseLink MOXy: Superclass fields are not set when unmarshaling

Tags: inheritance, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I would expect the fields of a superclass to be unmarshaled in the scenario below, but they are not. What is to do to make it work?

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a>my text</a>
```

Binding:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings
 xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
 package-name="test">

<java-types>        
  <java-type name="SubClass">
    <xml-root-element name="a"/>
    <java-attributes>
        <xml-element java-attribute="text" xml-path="text()" />
    </java-attributes>
  </java-type>
</java-types>

</xml-bindings>
```

Classes:

```
public class SuperClass {

 private String text;

 public String getText() {
    return text;
 }

 public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
 }
}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass { }
```

Demo:

```
Map<String, Object> jaxbContextProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>(1);
jaxbContextProperties.put(JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE, "bindings.xml");
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContextFactory.createContext(new Class[] {SuperClass.class}, jaxbContextProperties);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
SuperClass superClass = (SuperClass)unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("input.xml"));
System.out.println(superClass.getText());
```

Output:

```
[EL Warning]: 2013-07-31 15:09:16.602--Ignoring attribute [text] on class [SubClass] as no Property was generated for it.
null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mapping needs to be made on the class it belongs to.

### OPTION #1 - Map `SuperClass` Property On `SubClass`

If you want to map the super class properties as part of the child you need to mark the parent class transient on the `java-type` element.

**bindings.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings
    xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    package-name="forum17981925">
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="SuperClass" xml-transient="true"/>
        <java-type name="SubClass">
            <xml-root-element/>
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-element java-attribute="text" xml-path="text()" />
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

### OPTION #2 - Map `SuperClass` Property On `SuperClass`

Alternatively you could map the `text` property on `SuperClass`, this mapping with then be inherited by `SubClass`.

**bindings.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings
    xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    package-name="forum17981925">
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="SuperClass">
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-element java-attribute="text" xml-path="text()" />
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
        <java-type name="SubClass">
            <xml-root-element/>
        </java-type>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

### Demo Code

The following demo code can be run to prove that both options work:

**input.xml**

```xml
<subClass>Hello World</subClass>
```

**Demo**

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> jaxbContextProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>(1);
        jaxbContextProperties.put(JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE, "bindings.xml");
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContextFactory.createContext(new Class[] {SuperClass.class}, jaxbContextProperties);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        SuperClass superClass = (SuperClass)unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("input.xml"));
        System.out.println(superClass.getText());
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
Hello World
```

Comment: This works, thanks! Actually, I also have a second bindings file that already specifies the java-type (for a more general case). So I would have to override this java-type specification, which I tried here, but could not make it work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982654/eclipselink-moxy-override-rules-of-binding-files

Answer (score 0):

Also the **SuperClass's** field could be **null** - because your **SuperClass** doesn't have a **Setter** for his field, 
because Unmarshaller uses Default constructor with no arguments and **Setters** to initialize his fields. Or SuperClass doesn't have @**XmlRootElement** and @**XmlElement** annotations